# how to install cordova plugin through github url and set its configuration in config.xml

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-intent-action" spec="git+https://github.com/ngocdaothanh/cordova-plugin-intent-action.git" />
<plugin name="co.mylonas.cordova.applicationstate" spec="git+https://github.com/leomylonas/cordova-plugin-applicationstate.git" />
```

I'm trying to install those two plugins in my cordova application. When I run command *cordova plugin add --PluginName@gitURL--* it works. But when I run cordova platform add android, it gives me the following error.

[image]

Before I was using cordova 6.1.1 and node 6.9.5 and everything worked well. But after upgrading both, I'm seeing this issue.

NOTE: I'm using 
cordova 7.1.0
node 8.9.1
npm 5.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git+https` is a scheme only used by the git client. Just remove the `git+` part.

However I do not recommend you use remote repositories for plugins, because twice now, I have had such repositories disappear, either due to a name change, or it's simply deleted.

I suggest you clone it to a local path, check-out the desired tag/branch, remove the internal `.git` directory from it and commit the whole thing to your main project. You can add it as

```
<plugin name="the-plugin-name" spec="stored-plugins/that-important-plugin" />
```

Comment: But even those plugins, that are kept locally, are giving the same error. 
**Failed to get absolute path to installed module**
What do you suggest, how can I use these plugins with absolute path?

Comment: Simply removing the `git+` part should work for remote repositories. The suggestion about keeping them locally is merely if you don't trust people to maintain them in place, or not to update the specified branch (master when not specified) with backwards-incompatible changes.

Comment: Thanks @coladict, removing git+ worked for me. But can you please also help me in one more issue:
There is a plugin, which I'm adding from the local directory (not remote), but it is escaping some files. Like when I add IOS Platform, it ignores .framework file and similarly some files for Android.

Comment: I'm adding it this way:
<plugin name="cordova-background-geolocation" spec="resources/cordova-background-geolocation-2.8.5">

Comment: What do you mean it's escaping files?

Comment: I mean it copies the plugin form my local directory, but it ignores some files while copying.